# algorithm for analyzing description before saving into db: mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

The idea of application is to show all "E-number" ingredients within a product (E100, E200 etc.)

Imagine we have a list of products coming into our database (`JSONs`, scrapped or received via APIs). Products contain description - it describes ingredients within a product. 
Sometimes those ingredients already come with numbers (like E100), but sometimes there are names of ingredients (Octyl gallate), sometimes both.

We are going to store all these data in mongodb (collection prodcuts).

**The question** - now application queries given product and it has to show all E-numbers product contains. How would you solve the problem that descriptions has different forms (sometimes with direct E-numbers, sometimes with E-descriptions, sometimes with both etc.). Moreover sometimes in products' descriptions some E-descriptions are written incorreclty (with missing letters).

I do not thing that it would be good to do this on the fly, it would be better if all data would already be stored in DB (but not sure). So myr general solution could be like this:

- do preprocessing of description field when receiving products data and before saving product into DB (this could be done in any programming language - node.js for instance)
- during preprocessing we need to analyse descriptions field (thus searching within existing e-collection: e-id, e-name, e-category, **array of e-different-names**; for instance, if description contains E100, greens, Octyl gallate then during preprocessing we would get array "E100, E140, E311".
- then we would create "e-list" for products collection in json
- save product in db

Does this seems logical? Never worked with mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would make sense to process it while inserting and prepare data for quick queries. These ingredients could be normalized to separate collection and then add ingredient id-s to product.